# Flutter: How to Restart the application on OS level using MethodChannel

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

In production mode, Is there a way to fully restart the application (preferably with Kotlin MethodChannel)?

I have seen other answers recommend using a package (flutter_phoenix) but in my case I am making method calls before calling runApp(). Even then it does not seem to be restarting at OS level.

Also I have seen some Java Implementations, but the Imports used and function calls in Java applications do not seem to work with MethodChannel with flutter (even when Java support is selected over Kotlin)

Comment: You should be aware that restarting the application process programatically is not possible on iOS at all (you can just crash your app but this approach has obvious downsides)